# Is there a way to describe the pattern of a signal as a numeric value?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, modulation, information-theory, pattern

I've been digging a little into signal processing and I just started a networks and telecommunications class at college. We saw there are different encode techniques Amplitude, Frequency and Phase shift keying (ASK, BFSK and BPSK). Using this techniques one can form different patterns in a signal to encode information, a "message".

I want to know if there is any numerical value that can be related to a signal pattern, to the "message" this pattern encodes. For example, if I have 2 signals with different information encoded in eachone (using the same encoded techniques and standards), is there any measure I can get from this signal, that can show the patterns are different?

I am quite new at this topics and I haven't had any luck in books and papers, I hope someone can help me.

***EDIT***

I'm looking for either a metric, a statistic, a parameter, a measurement that will (at least) be most likely to change if the pattern of the signal (that should depend on the information encoded in it) chage.

*Here a little analogy I thought of*
Let's say we have 2 signals which by any type of modulation, encode:

signal1 = [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]
signal2 = [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0]

Both time series have the same amount of 1's and 0's, so a thing like mean or variance will not tell me if both signals encode a different thing.

I thought of meausring the average change of each time series, I think of the change as the difference of each sample with the next one (in this case difference is either 0 or 1, from 0 to 1 and viceversa is 1, and from 0 to 0 or 1 to 1 the difference will be 0). This approach does give me different values for each time series, but I am looking for a better founded approach.

Comment: not quite following you – the points from the modulation schemes *are* numbers. are you asking us whether there's a distance metric on numbers? (there is: absolute difference, for example)

Comment: @MarcusMüller yeah, I mean, anything that can help me to distinguish (even with a certain amount of error) if two signals encode a different thing, i. e. if 2 patterns are equal, similar, or different from eachother

Comment: yeah, a distance metric on your signal space. For many linear things that can be cross-correlation (or its absolute), which often technically simplifies to euclidean distance after a matched filter (under a lot of assumptions on signal and channel). You're getting into receivers then, whose sole job is to decide what was transmitted. Chances are high your course will touch on these soon!